# Error: no space left on device Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

[image]

I am getting an error on ubunto while openning the terminal saying the following:
Bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left ok device

Although there exists space already.. 
This error has encountered suddenly when i was working on sublime text

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you may want to check your inode usage as well:

`df -i`

it's possible to get "no space left on device" when you have space available, but you're out of inodes.

http://web.archive.org/web/20210514092503/https://scoutapm.com/blog/understanding-disk-inodes

Comment: Could this happen after a recent disk cleanup? Is there a way of reclaiming this space without a reboot?

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem. In my case after login in, the screen would not show icons and only the cursor. Even auto completion in bash-terminal threw an error of out-of-memory.

I tried unmounting `/tmp`, `apt-get autoclean`, `apt-get clean` nothing worked.

In my case deleting large files in ~/.cache worked.

```
cd ~/.cache
du -sh *
rm -fr <large files/folders>
```

Generally, deleting files in .cache is not harmful but still be careful.
In my case thumbnails and pip folders were the culprit taking 1G and 3.6G respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Run `df -h` and see if there are any folders that are 100% full. Looks like `/tmp` may be full.